# Can we find a such function?

Tags: real-analysis

is it possible for a Caratheodory function (measurable at x and continuous at s) $G:\mathbb{R}^N\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{s\to+\infty} \frac{G(x,s)}{\lvert\,s\,\rvert^{m}}=+\infty, ~ x\in \Omega$$

and

$$\lim_{s\to+\infty} \frac{G(x,s)}{\lvert\,s\,\rvert^{m}}<+\infty, ~ x\in \Omega^c$$

where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set from $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $m>1, N\geq2$

Comment: you want an example of such a function?

Comment: it must be continuous or at least  measurable % x and continuous % s, there is no contradiction between the two hypothesis ?

Comment: Then you must include these in your post then

Comment: Also $N$ can be one? or it must be stricly bigger than 1?

Comment: i edited my question @MariosGretsas

Answer (score 2):

I suggest
$$G(x, s) = |s|^{m + d(x, \Omega^c)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes :
$$\forall x, s \in \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}, G(x, s) := d(x) e^s$$
where $d$ is the distance to $\Omega^c$.